# Include columns without counts in ggplot barchart for easier comparison with other barcharts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a series of barcharts that I am creating with ggplot for a presentation.

The data being presented are questionnaire responses which have six possible answers (likert  scale).

The data is "narrow" to allow for a grouped barchart to show the previous years results as well as the latest ones.

The variable column holds the question names (more than just the one shown here) and the value column the answers given.

data.melted:

```
    Survey          Group          variable            value
1   2012            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
2   2012            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
3   2012            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
4   2012            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Very well
5   2012            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
6   2012            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
7   2012            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
8   2012            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Very well
9   2012            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
10  2012            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
11  2013            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Very well
12  2013            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
13  2013            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
14  2013            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
15  2013            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
16  2013            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
17  2013            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
18  2013            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
19  2013            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
20  2013            Out.patients   Understood.carer    Extremely well
```

Code:

```
library("ggplot2")

data.melted <- structure(list(Survey = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2012", "2013"), class = 
"factor"), Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Out.patients", class = "factor"), variable = 
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "Understood.carer", class = "factor"),     value = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Not 
applicable", "Not at all", "Slightly", "Quite well", "Very well", "Extremely well"), 
class = c("ordered", "factor"))), .Names = c("Survey", "Group", "variable", "value"), 
row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")

order1 <- c("Not applicable", "Not at all","Slightly","Quite well","Very well","Extremely well")

data.melted$value <- factor(data.melted$value, levels=order1, ordered=TRUE)

ggplot(data.melted[which(data.melted$variable=="Understood.carer"),], aes(value, fill=Survey)) + geom_histogram(position="dodge", colour="black") + xlab("Score") + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=15, hjust=1, vjust=1))
```

The graph from the data given:
[image: Graph]
The problem is that some of the questions (as in the example data) do not have answers at each level, so when the graph is produced there are only the grouped columns for two or three of the possible six answers (as with the above data).

For ease of comparison people want all the possible answers on all graphs, even if there are no counts for the answers.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `discrete_scale` function has an argument `limits`, that you can use to define what levels should be shown:

```
scale_x_discrete(name="Score", limits=levels(data.melted$value))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the prompt reply :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xlim()`, or alternatively `scale_x_discrete()`, to specify the domain of your x-axis.

```
ggplot(data.melted[which(data.melted$variable=="Understood.carer"),], aes(value, fill=Survey)) + 
geom_histogram(position="dodge", colour="black") + xlab("Score") + 
scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=15, hjust=1, vjust=1)) + xlim(order1)
```

I also suggest you to paste data in the format given by `dput()`, because reading it from fixed-width text is a pain.

Comment: Thanks also for the prompt reply. Seeing as shadow was first I have ticked his answer.

Comment: How is it I should I should post the data? Should I just copy the output of dput(data.melted) from R into the question using the code formatting, or do it some other way?

Comment: Yes, that's it. It's just easier to copy something into an R console :-)